# How to Use RadioButtonGroup Control with Indirect Property?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I am working on a installer using WIX Toolset which have a dialog, which takes a few inputs from user and pass them to parent dialog. For POC I did that for Edit Control that worked perfectly.
But when I tried same using RadioButtonGroup It fails with

```
Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:_TestRb' in section 'Fragment:'.(LGHT0094)
```

below is my parent dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <DialogRef Id="spandlg"></DialogRef>
            <Property Id="TestProp" Value="Test"></Property>
            <Property Id="TestRadio" Value="1"></Property>
            <Dialog Id="parent_dlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="parent.dlg">
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next">
                    <Publish Property="_TestRb" Value="TestRadio" Order="2">1</Publish>
                    <Publish Property="_TestP" Value="TestProp" Order="1">1</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="spandlg" Order="3">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="txtBox" Type="Edit" Height="15" Width="321" X="10" Y="16" Property="TestRadio"></Control>
                <Control Id="txtBox1" Type="Edit" Height="15" Width="321" X="10" Y="50" Property="TestProp"></Control>
                <Control Id="c" Type="PushButton" X="300" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Cancel">
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Exit" Order="2">1</Publish>
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

and this is dialog to be opened as Spawn

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="spandlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="spandlg">
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="[Button_Next]">                 
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"></Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="textBox1" Type="Edit" Height="15" Width="176" X="9" Y="9" Property="_TestP" Indirect="yes" />
                <Control Id="radioButtonGroupBox1" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Height="75" Width="150" X="10" Y="36" 
                         Property="_TestRb" Indirect="yes"  >
                    <RadioButtonGroup Property="_TestRb">
                        <RadioButton X="3" Y="26" Height="18" Width="78" Text="radioButton2" Value="0" />
                        <RadioButton X="3" Y="3" Height="18" Width="78" Text="radioButton1" Value="1" />
                    </RadioButtonGroup>
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I can't get what's wrong with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the Issue after removing,

```
<Control Id="txtBox" Type="Edit" Height="15" Width="321" X="10" Y="16" Property="TestRadio"></Control>
```

from *parent_dlg* dialog.

It looks like, as Edit Control can change value of property *TestRadio* other then `0` and `1` which are invalid according to [ICE34](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368958(v=vs.85).aspx). But Error Message `Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:_TestRb' in section 'Fragment:'` was not at all helpful.

After defining Property *_TestRb* actual error was shown `ICE34: 1 is not a valid default value for the property TestRadio. The property is an indirect RadioButtonGroup property of control spandlg.radioButtonGroupBox1 (via property _TestRb). (LGHT0204)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the property somewhere.  Something like

```
<Property Id="_TestRb" />
```

Maybe you swapped Property and Value attributes?

Comment: I have Tried, it does not help. property `_TestP` too is not defined similar to `_TestRb` but with that there is no problem.

Comment: Hi @dvorn,
Below is the error i am getting after defining _TestRb `<Property Id="_TestRb" Value="TestRadio"></Property>` 

**ICE34: 1 is not a valid default value for the property TestRadio. The property is an indirect RadioButtonGroup property of control spandlg.radioButtonGroupBox1 (via property _TestRb). (LGHT0204) - parent.dlg.wxs**